# How can I disable smart indentation in emacs (and force either spaces or tabs)?

Tags: emacs

I want to make emacs insert either 4 spaces or a tab when I press the tab key. Nothing else. I don't want smart indentation, I don't want it to auto-align itself or try to do anything smart. I just want it to output 4 spaces (or a tab). =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that each mode in emacs defines the TAB key diferently. To get a global behavior, look at Trey Jackson's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344966/sane-tab-in-emacs

```
 (defvar just-tab-keymap (make-sparse-keymap) "Keymap for just-tab-mode")
 (define-minor-mode just-tab-mode
   "Just want the TAB key to be a TAB"
   :global t :lighter " TAB" :init-value 0 :keymap just-tab-keymap
   (define-key just-tab-keymap (kbd "TAB") 'indent-for-tab-command))
```

You may want to use `'self-insert-command` instead of `'indent-for-tab-command` as pointed out by another person answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

Find your .emacs and add this:

```
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

this make your emacs inserts 2 spaces, you can change the number and put 4,

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

if you want spaces NO tabs