# How can I setup emacs to change space to TAB character for indent?

Tags: linux, emacs

I am writing code for Linux kernel driver.

The [coding standard said](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/newbies-guide-hacking-linux-kernel)

`The first rule that everyone needs to follow is to use the Tab character rather than spaces, to indent code. Also, the Tab character should represent eight spaces. Following along with the eight-character Tab indentation, the code should not flow past the 80 character line limit on the right of the screen.`

Can you please tell me how can I change to use TAB character to space in emacs for indenting?

And use a eight character tab indentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 8 200 8))
(setq tab-width 8)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

To make it mode specific you can do something like this (just substitute `michael-special-mode-hook` with whatever mode you are using to write your code):

```
(add-hook 'michael-special-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
  (setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 8 200 8))
  (setq tab-width 8)
  (setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab) ))
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer; you might want to consider posting it again in [the linked question](http://superuser.com/questions/268029/how-can-i-disable-smart-indentation-in-emacs-and-force-either-spaces-or-tabs).